# Extendable custom collection types in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am working on cleaning up sequence types in genalgo, a bioinformatics library for Scala, but I am running into an issue.

In genalgo, there are biological sequences (DNA, RNA, Protein) which all extend the `BioSequence` trait. Right now, if you call methods like `drop` on a DNA/RNA/Protein you get back the type you started out with. However, if you have a method with a type parameter that is set to extend `BioSequence`, calling methods such as `drop` on an object of that type returns an `IndexedSeq` but I want it to return the original type. As a workaround (https://github.com/shadaj/genalgo/commit/8c2756d214b4bcf1b8994c321c6587da7922b9fd), I have overrided `drop` in `BioSequence` to call the super method and cast the result to the original type. Even with this fix, only `drop` is fixed but other methods still return `IndexedSeq`s.

Here is a distilled example (and a [fiddle](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/c7b2a00e1245f603516b) if you want to try it online):

```
object Example {
  import scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike

  trait BaseLike

  class DNABase extends BaseLike

  trait BioSequence[B <: BaseLike] extends IndexedSeq[B]

  class DNA extends BioSequence[DNABase] with IndexedSeqLike[DNABase, DNA] {
    def length = 1
    def apply(idx: Int) = {
      new DNABase
    }
  }

  val myDNA = new DNA
  val droppedDNA: DNA = myDNA.drop(1) // Works because DNA extends IndexedSeqLike
  def processSequence[B <: BaseLike, C <: BioSequence[B]](seq: C): C = {
    seq.drop(1) // Doesn't work because BioSequence doesn't extend IndexedSeqLike
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Not enough info to be able answer question. Dont link to repos and expect people to follow them, try to include minimum code necessary to ask question. If that means a lot of code, maybe a question for the code review site.

Comment: @samthebest I'm not sure what you mean. The code block at the bottom (the `Example` object) is all that is needed to reproduce the issue. In addition, I have provided a fiddle to make it easy to test out the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @samthebest commented there isn't enough information to fully answer the question, but maybe this will help

```
def processSequence[B <: BaseLike, C <% BioSequence[B] with IndexedSeqLike[B, C]](seq: C): C = 
  seq.drop(1)
```

Comment: Nice usage of view bound! (Shame they are deprecated, can you refactor to use context bound?)

Comment: Thanks. This gave me a good idea of where to go, and in this case since there are no implicit conversions required it works without using a view bound as in `def processSequence[B <: BaseLike, C <% BioSequence[B] with IndexedSeqLike[B, C]](seq: C): C = seq.drop(1)`

Comment: BTW, in case you're curious here is the commit based on the discussion. https://github.com/shadaj/genalgo/commit/f7d5a22fae5b0d48dadee4e1fc0f31a3e17a0d77